# How to avoid overlapping Clicks?

Tags: android, onclick

I'm using a Relative Layout where I've placed a Button over an Image View.

The problem is I've used `OnClick` on both button and Image View that refers to different methods i.e., button when clicked calls a method, Image when clicked calls a different method. When I click on the button the App force quits i.e., has a Runtime Exception.

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<Button
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="click"
       android:onClick="sampleClick"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
       android:id="@+id/button" />

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/oreo"
       android:onClick="imageClick"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public void sampleClick(View view){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button Click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    public void imageClick(View view){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image Click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Help me solve the Error.

[image]

Comment: post the error logs

Comment: **_Help me solve the Error_** . First tell what is the error. paste the error log

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya for what ? ahaha its easy task why hi should using frame_layout ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove onClick from layout xml file, set click listeners on view at runtime

In java file

```
//setting click listeners

findViewById(R.id.imageView).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(this);

//implement you java class with View.OnClickListener interface and override onClick method

@Override
public void onClick(View v){

       switch(v.getId()){

             case R.id.imageView:
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image Click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  break;

             case R.id.button:
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Button Click",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  break;

       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch them around.

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:srcCompat="@drawable/oreo"
   android:onClick="imageClick"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="click"
   android:onClick="sampleClick"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
   android:id="@+id/button" />
```

This way the Button will be 'on top of' the ImageView